# How do I fire alert message when clicking on disabled <select> option box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert

I want to fire an alert if clicking on a disabled `<select>` option box. When the `<select>` box is not disabled it should not fire, regardless if the option within the option select is disabled.

**It should ONLY fire when the entire `<select>` box is disabled, regardless if the individual option itself is disabled or enabled. An individual option alone should not effect the alert.**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#optDir').click(function(){
        alert("The Box is dissabled... ``Text Direction`` can only be chosen, when choosing ``Auto Detect`` languadge");
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "auto") {
                $("#optDir").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $("#optDir").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })
    });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function setRtL(obj) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("SeekBox");
    textbox.style.direction = ["ar","RightToLeft"].indexOf(obj.value) >=0 ? "rtl" : "ltr";
}
</script>

<div id="Layer1" style="position:relative; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:auto;z-index:1;">

<select name="LangF" class="OBSMatch" id="opt" onchange="setRtL(this)">
  <option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
  <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
  <option selected value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
</select>

<select disabled name="LangF" class="dis-element" id="optDir" onchange="setRtL(this)" title="``Text Direction`` can only be chosen, when choosing ``Auto Detect`` languadge">
  <option selected value="" disabled>Only with: Auto Detect</option>
  <option value="">Text: Left To Right</option>
  <option value="RightToLeft">Text: Right To Left</option>
</select>

</div>
```

**NOTE: All model codes are simplified, the entire work is much bigger.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled elements don't trigger any mouse events. So you can't capture click even from disabled select box. You can keep a wrapper div around it and then put onclick event on it from there you can get the select element using `.siblings()` and check if it has disabled property. 
You will have to remove the wrapper div when you enable the select. for that you can `hide()` the wrapper div and show it again when needed.

Something like this seems to work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function checkDisableSelect(obj){
   var select = $(obj).siblings('#optDir').first();
   if($(select).attr('disabled'))
       alert("The Box is dissabled... ``Text Direction`` can only be chosen, when choosing ``Auto Detect`` languadge");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#opt").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "auto") {
                $("#optDir").prop('disabled', false);
                $('#selectWrapper').hide();
            } else {
                $("#optDir").prop('disabled', true);
                $('#selectWrapper').show();
            }
        })
    });
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function setRtL(obj) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("SeekBox");
    textbox.style.direction = ["ar","RightToLeft"].indexOf(obj.value) >=0 ? "rtl" : "ltr";
}
</script>




<select name="LangF" class="OBSMatch" id="opt" onchange="setRtL(this)">
  <option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
  <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
  <option selected value="en">English</option>
  <option value="fr">French</option>
  <option value="de">German</option>
  <option value="ru">Russian</option>
  <option value="es">Spanish</option>
</select>
<div id="selectContainer" style="position:relative">
<select disabled name="LangF" class="dis-element" id="optDir" onchange="setRtL(this)" title="``Text Direction`` can only be chosen, when choosing ``Auto Detect`` languadge">
  <option selected value="" disabled>Only with: Auto Detect</option>
  <option value="">Text: Left To Right</option>
  <option value="RightToLeft">Text: Right To Left</option>
</select>
<div id="selectWrapper" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;" onclick="checkDisableSelect(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although it works perfectly when tested, when put on the page the div box of ``position:absolute`` is putting itself above the ``option`` box making it impossible to click on the option box when it is enabled. So I need to find out what is going on, till now this has not happened.

Comment: did you use the updated code, you will need to hide the div if you enable select, i have added the code for that.

Comment: Okay now I know were the problem is and I fixed it. By confidence your div had the same name as another div on the page, and I was looking like a cat on a calendar trying to figure out what is going on. LOL Anyway now it is fixed.

Comment: Now the problem is that the entire code you gave sits in another div ``<div id="Layer1" style="position:relative; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:auto;z-index:1;"> <HERE IS YOUR CODE> </div>`` and that div is having effect with your div making it not work. I need to somehow make them both coexisting.

Comment: it is difficult to understand like this, you should have put all code in the question.

Comment: I did not think that the other div box would have any significance, it usually does not. But okay I will update it.

Comment: Normally a person simplifies the code, because one should not put the entire webpage file here.