# Element keypress when mouse hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a function when the input keypressed on disabled element.

```js
$(".example").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("enter pressed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="example" disabled/>
```

I am trying to on hover method but i can't succesfull.

This is jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/vL9emkzL/

Edit second fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/vL9emkzL/1

Comment: `disabled` elements cannot raise events, so what you're trying to do is not possible. As a workaround you could use `readonly` instead, but that may have a knock-on effect depending on how you're using the input

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It doesn't work with readonly too cause the element must be focused to trigger the keypress event. - My bad, bad manipulation. it works fine

Comment: Sir , when i make readonly i can change the input look at this code block https://jsfiddle.net/vL9emkzL/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fire alert message when clicking on disabled <select> option box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271249/how-do-i-fire-alert-message-when-clicking-on-disabled-select-option-box)

Comment: @Alexis readonly works fine (at least in Chrome) https://jsfiddle.net/vL9emkzL/3/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've test with a `blur()` on focus, sorry. Your solution works

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , can you look at the my new jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Whats the use-case? Why do you want an event (keypress) on a disabled element?

Comment: @MilanChheda , i want to open a popup when press enter the input. But i don't want to someone change my input.

Comment: As I understand correctly, once the user has entered a value in the input and pressed enter, a popup should open, right? Will the user enter a value or is the field disabled always?

Comment: yeah sir. its correct.

Comment: add or remove read-only attr using jquery instead of binding it directly

Answer (score 1):

Use readonly instead of disabled. disabled elements can't emit events.

```js
$(".example").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("enter pressed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="example" readonly/>
```

Comment: @ZibianDomichi its working. when i press enter key alert is coming.

Comment: But its not readonly you can change the input values. I don't want to change to input.

Comment: maskMoney is making it to take input values. try removing maskMoney and check it works.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what we can do:

1. As you mentioned, user will enter a value in the input field and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. So when user presses the enter, disable this field and open the popup.

So instead of making it readonly or disabled from the beginning, we can make it disabled only when he presses <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```js
$(".example").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    console.log("enter pressed and field is disabled.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="example" />
```